# Unable to perform database backup using sybase central

Tags: sql, database, backup, sybase, sqlanywhere

Error:

```
The storage control block address is invalid unable to determine disk freespace
```

- SQL Anywhere 9
- Sybase Central 4.3
- Windows XP

How to resolve this problem?

Button to choose dir is not activated.

I tried also type local and network dir, both the same result (error above).

Comment: Have you tried doing it via command-line - also, can you change the `//` to \\ in the dump command?  I seem to recall a bug in old versions of SQL Anywhere regarding pathnames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Problem was because, I typed wrong DIR path.
>
> I tried to perform buckup not directly on server, but by the local workstation.
>
> I typed my local machine DIR path and network DIR path.
>
> However correct DIR path, was the local SERVER machine DIR path.